# Search for Public Google Plus Hangouts I can join

Tags: google-plus, google-hangouts

For a while now I can only see **On Air** Hangouts. I can't join those.

How can I search in Google Plus for Public, "joinable" (not On Air) Hangouts?

Answer (score 1):

You just have to look for posts tagged with the #hangoutpost hashtag

https://plus.google.com/s/%23hangoutpost/hangouts

Comment: Apparently the "#hangoutpost tag is totally dead". :( — https://plus.google.com/+ChrisJenkins/posts/BbvhNGKcEpq

Answer (score 0):

List of public Google+ Hangouts sorted by category:
http://gphangouts.com/